# MySQL Query to display timesheet table data like a weekly calendar

Tags: mysql

I am working on a timesheet program. I want to extract the timesheet data of a single account from my DTR Table and display it like a weekly calendar. Here is an example of my DTR table:

```
DTR TABLE (select * from DTR where empbio=12934;)
+--------+------------+----------+-----------+
| empbio | dtr_date   | dtr_time | in_or_out |
+--------+------------+----------+-----------+
|  12934 | 2016-08-22 | 15:52:21 | 0         |
|  12934 | 2016-08-22 | 15:58:54 | 1         |
|  12934 | 2016-08-22 | 19:20:16 | 1         |
|  12934 | 2016-08-23 | 08:30:51 | 0         |
|  12934 | 2016-08-24 | 07:36:47 | 0         |
|  12934 | 2016-08-24 | 07:48:40 | 0         |
|  12934 | 2016-08-24 | 18:08:55 | 1         |
|  12934 | 2016-08-25 | 08:11:11 | 0         |
|  12934 | 2016-08-25 | 18:23:06 | 1         |
|  12934 | 2016-08-26 | 19:22:46 | 1         |
+--------+------------+----------+-----------+
10 row(s)
```

0 means login and 1 means logout. If you look closely on the table, there can be multiple login or logout within a single day (dates 2016-08-22 and 2016-08-24). There are also a cases of failure to login (2016-08-26) or logout(2016-08-23).

I want to display it like a weekly calendar using one single query. Notice that 0s and 1s are replaced with the words IN or OUT. I believe the mysql concat function would be very useful in combining multiple data in one row. Please help me solve this.

```
Expected MySQL Query Output
+-------------+---------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| 2016-08-22  | 2016-08-23    | 2016-08-24  | 2016-08-25  | 2016-08-26  |
+-------------+---------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| 15:52:21 IN | 08:30:51 IN   | 07:36:47 IN | 08:11:11 IN | 19:22:46 OUT|
| 15:58:54 OUT|               | 07:48:40 IN | 18:23:06 OUT|             |
| 19:20:16 OUT|               | 18:08:55 OUT|             |             |
+-------------+---------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
1 row(s)
```

Comment: my advice would be don't use SQL to try and format the data for presentation. It's not really designed for that. Just extract the data from the database and use your programming language's UI to present the data to users. If it's a web-based app there are quite a few plugins around which can help you display calendar data, e.g. FullCalendar